# Mac Google Chrome Not Responding; how to investigate and fix?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Just now while using Chrome with an infinite number of tabs and windows, it stopped responding with a colorful spinwheel. The computer is still working, but every other application moves 30x slower whereby every action I make will be delayed by ~2 seconds, even if its a simple click. I waited for about 10 minutes to unlag but its still the same.

I opened activity monitor and started quitting all Chrome subprocesses. After about 3 minutes, computer is completely fine now, but Chrome main process is still showing as not responding:

[image]

How do I investigate what's going wrong? And how can it be fixed?

---

(Btw, I remembered having a similar issue 2 months ago and I managed to fix that one after much googling, but I can't remember how I fixed it.)

Answer (score 1):

My friend, ask yourself how deep you desire to know and how far you are willing to go.  If you desire merely a working Chrome, reinstall it and hope that all will go better.

If you want more than that, then let us explore what tracing and profiling can tell us.  You will need Xcode and need the command-line tools installed.  If you have chrome still running, then pull up a Terminal, and let’s profile chrome for a minute when it starts beach-ballin’.

```
sudo sample $( pgrep Chrome ) 60 -f ~/Desktop/chrome.profile.txt
```

You can also use Instruments for the same:

```
sudo instruments -l 60000 -t Time\ Profiler -p $( pgrep Chrome )
```

You likely will spot something in there that takes up most of the time.  Time now for trace.  When you are ready, straight bust a dtruss on Chrome, to see the low level:

```
sudo dtruss -a -f -n Chrome 2> ~/Desktop/Chrome.trace.txt
```

Let it run for a minute.  Then stop with CONTROL-C, as I recall, off the top of my head.  Then examine that trace file!

Enjoy, and Good Yule,

F.

Comment: I ran `dtruss` on the stuck Chrome for a couple of minutes and ctrlC it. This is the output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16bueYrulbH23Loj6WO-esnTtjIM52xmU/view?usp=sharing .

Comment: For Chrome `sample` is it safe to post the output? In any case, how am I supposed to read it to see what has went wrong?

Comment: Simply open the files we created on your desktop.    Files we named chrome.profile.txt and chrome.trace.txt.

Comment: Make sure to run those commands as root.  Without the ‘sudo’ part, the output is meaningless given privilege restriction.

Comment: Change end of dtruss line to read ‘> ~/Desktop/Chrome.trace.txt 2>&1’

Comment: We forgot to circumvent system integrity.  Boot into recovery mode with COMMAND-R at boot.  Open Terminal.  Type ‘csrutil enable —without dtrace’.  Reboot and run dtruss.  To restore original ‘csrutil enable’ at the next terminal in recovery mode.

Comment: After I changed dtruss this is what i get: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VtzMG1As8tBS8ZIDdtjme6m60yGg6u6O/view . I can't reboot or I would lose the tab information in the incognito windows of the stuck Chrome. I can open `sample` output , but its a weird output **how** *should* I read it? Is it safe to post its contents output?

Comment: We forgot to disable system integrity so that dtrace works.  I left instructions above.

Comment: Is there a way without restart? I remembered this problem can be solved without restart as I had done that once before 2 mths ago, but I can't remember how it's done or whether it involves using Console or Sample or anything.

Comment: Perhaps you really just wanted to refresh chrome : ‘kill -1 $( pgrep Chrome )’.  We loose the opportunity to properly diagnose in this case...

Answer (score 0):

This helped me! Chrome unfroze and is running perfectly now.

https://www.wikihow.com/Un-Pause-an-Application-(Mac-OS-X)

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. We expect answers to be self contained, since if your link goes down, your answer will be useless. Paraphrasing the source and including any relevant information in the answer will ensure it stays relevant. Also, please make it more clear how the procedure described in the linked page solves the specific problem described in the question.